# Kafka-topics --list using ssl

Tags: apache-kafka

Can any body help the command to list the kafka topics using SSl .

I have got consumer SSL config and producer SSL config commands but dint find the way to list Kafka topics using SSl.

Comment: Using Zookeeper or bootstrap-server?

Answer (score 13):

You should be able to do that by using the `--bootstrap-server` option, so specifying Kafka brokers in the bootstrap list, and then the `--command-config` providing a property file with the admin client configuration parameters.

Inside that properties file you should specify `ssl.truststore.location` and `ssl.truststore.password` (eventually `ssl.truststore.type`) as you normally do for producer and consumer clients.

If TLS client authentication is enabled, you have to set `ssl.keystore.location` and `ssl.keystore.password` as well.

Comment: Can you please give an example for context? How does that file look like?

Comment: Sample config 

```
ssl.truststore.location=/truststore.jks
ssl.truststore.password=abc123
```

Answer (score -6):

As of my knowledge, the Consumer and Producer SSL config does not actually make a difference if you want to fetch the list of Kafka topics. Just simply try the cli command:

**./bin/kafka-topics --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list**

or

**./bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list**

Comment: The "--zookeeper" option was deprecated in Apache Kafka 2.2, you should not rely on it.

Comment: Your answer does not help or give a pointer how to query the topics with TLS/SSL.

Comment: Although --zookeeper is deprecated, kafka-topics.sh in a secure environment works with --zookeeper option only. There is no option to provide a separate config like in console-producer/consumer.
The command that worked for me in SSL/TLS environment: `/bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --list`

Comment: FYI, I've been trying to connect to a Zookeeper TLS port on Amazon MSK this way and it simply hangs.  Using `--bootstrap` and the TLS broker list instead works, and `kafka-topics.sh` accepts the `--command-config` option.  The config file requires only `security.protocol=SSL` (unless you're using client certificates.)